# Error Installing react-tinder-card dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

Im trying to install react-tinder-card and gives me this error I dont know how to solve it, any help?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree       
npm ERR! While resolving: tinder_clone_react@0.1.0        
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-tinder-card@1.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-tinder-card
npm ERR!   react-tinder-card@"*" from the root project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an error due to a mismatch in `react` versions: `react-tinder-card` wants the `16.8.0` but in your project you have the `17.0.2`.

In order to resolve this problem you could downgrade your react version down to `16` (not recommended) or you could fork the `react-tinder-card`, update the package in order to accept `react@17` as peer-depedency and check if everything works.

I suggest you also to open an issue on `react-tinder-card` and ask them to do the same thing (upgrade the react version in peer depedencies).