# Failed to compile Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/unstable-native-dependencies'

Tags: javascript, css, solidity

I'm trying to run this web app from https://github.com/CleverProgrammers/tinder-blockchain-youtube but I'm getting the following error:

[Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhZh2.png)

```
./node_modules/react-panresponder-web/dist/panresponder.js:7:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/unstable-native-dependencies'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/react-tinder-card/index.js
./components/TinderCardItem.js
./components/Card.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Please someone help me out!

Comment: Please post the error message as text so it's easier for answerers to copy-paste parts of the message and troubleshoot your issue. You can wrap it in markdown block with three backticks `\`\`\``

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/3DJakob/react-tinder-card/issues/100) for a simialr issue from the package's official Github page and [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521588/error-installing-react-tinder-card-dependency) mentioning incompatibe React versions - might help point you in the right direction. This happens quite a lot and sometimes it's an easy fix and other times you can wait for the package author/s to update or fix the issue or raise an issue on their Github page, similar to how you asked the question here.

Comment: @PetrHejda I just checked and _answerers_ is a real word jic [question on English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214155/does-the-word-answerers-exist)

Answer (score 0):

I was expiriencing the same issue until I decided to use an earlier version of react-tinder-card .  Try installing this , it might work for you too `npm i react-tinder-card@1.5.4`